# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "image_file_name" of relation "articles" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, database-migration, heroku-postgres

Can someone please help me with runing `heroku run db:migrate`? I've forgot to run db:migration on heroku along with migration on dev env. I made coulple of them and now I'm receiving the below error:

```
wozane:~/workspace (master) $ heroku run rake db:migrate                           
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ wozane... up, run.7786
   (0.8ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(96974639112725850);
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to RemoveColumnImage (20160917131520)
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
== 20160917131520 RemoveColumnImage: migrating ================================
-- remove_column(:articles, :image_file_name, :string)
   (1.5ms)  ALTER TABLE "articles" DROP "image_file_name"
   (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.8ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(96974639112725850)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "image_file_name" of relation "articles" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "articles" DROP "image_file_name"
```

The case is that this column has been deleted and it doesn't exist.

Migration mentioned in the error message (number 20160917131520):

```
class RemoveColumnImage < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    remove_column :articles, :image_file_name , :string
    remove_column :articles, :image_content_type, :string
    remove_column :articles, :image_file_size, :integer
    remove_column :articles, :image_updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Schema.rb looks like that:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160921115118) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "img_url"
  end

  create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "img_url"
    t.text     "text"
  end

end
```

I tried to `#`the whole code in migration and it didn't help along with those comments which did not work:

```
rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=production
heroku run rake db:reset 
heroku run rake db:migrate -app wozane
heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm wozane
```

Does anyone have an idea how to run the heroku migration in my case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your articles table doesn't seem to have any of the columns you are trying to remove.

Comment: I removed it with the migration earlier. The problem is that I did't do `heroku run rake db:migrate` at that time and maybe too many other changes happened in-between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just comment out code of remove column migration.

```
class RemoveColumnImage < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    #remove_column :articles, :image_file_name , :string
    #remove_column :articles, :image_content_type, :string
    #remove_column :articles, :image_file_size, :integer
    #remove_column :articles, :image_updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

And try to run **`heroku run rake db:migrate -app wozane`**

Comment: Migrating to RemoveColumnImage (20160917131520)
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN

== 20160917131520 RemoveColumnImage: migrating 

-- remove_column(:articles, :image_file_name, :string)
   (5.1ms)  ALTER TABLE "articles" DROP "image_file_name"

   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
   (3.5ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(96974639112725850)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "image_file_name" of relation "articles" does not exist

: ALTER TABLE "articles" DROP "image_file_name"

Comment: Have you commented only lines of remove_column? @Wozane And also check the name of migration contains version number 20160917131520?

Comment: I commented only that line and the whole migration.
The whole migration no 20160917131520 is attached above.

Comment: Then how it is possible that you commented lines of code runs on heroku . Please confirm you have added your commented lines of code on heroku.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that you meant to comment lines of code on heroku. I just commented them normaly. Please advise how can I comment code on heroku.

Comment: Just comment your code in local system and push that changed code to heorku and then run migration on heorku.